# Based on condition how to set boolean value of a directive - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

In angular,I have a directive that takes a boolean input.

I have an anchor tag in html, where this directive is used.
Now  I want to set the directive's Boolean value based on
the anchor tag's href value.
If anchor tag's URL starts with "http:" then I want to pass yes
to the Boolean value and no if otherwise.

How to achieve this in angular html component. Below is my code

```
**newWindow is the directive
isExternalLink is a input to the directive**


 <a href="{{ object.Url}}" 
newWindow Name="{{ object.Name }}" isExternalLink={{ here should apply
 the condition based on the object.URL.startswith and send yes/ no }} >{{object.Name}} </a>      

export class newWindow {
  @Input() Name: string;
  @Input() isExternalLink : string;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegExp to test if the url starts with `http:`

Add a getter to wrap the condition

Template

```
<a href="{{ object.Url}}" 
   newWindow Name="{{ object.Name }}" [isExternalLink]={{ isExternal }} > 
  {{object.Name}} </a>
```

Component class:

```
export class MyComponent {
  get isExternal(): boolean {
    // If you want to test https too: use /^https?:/ instead
    return /^http:/.test(this.object.Url)
  }

  // ...
}
```

---

Alternative:

If you don't want to deal with regexp, use the String method [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```
get isExternal(): boolean {
  return this.object.Url.startsWith('http:')
}
```

---

**Update**:

If you want to make it inline:

```
<a href="{{ object.Url}}" 
       newWindow Name="{{ object.Name }}" [isExternalLink]={{ object.Url.startsWith('http:') }} > 
      {{object.Name}} </a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, is there a way where I can check in the HTML template itself ? Something like this : Just curious !
 
<a href="{{ object.Url}}" 
newWindow Name="{{ object.Name }}" isExternalLink="object.Url.startsWith('http')? 'yes' : 'no'"  >{{object.Name}} </a>

Comment: it works, slight syntax change --- [isExternalLink]="object.Url.startsWith('http') ? 'yes' : 'no'"